# How can I draw data 2D at differents points as fenceplot at Gnuplot, with a background transparent?

Tags: plot, 3d, 2d, gnuplot, fence-plots

I have three files where each file is 2D with an x-axis vs y-axis. I plot these files as fenceplot at Gnuplot.

With this code

```
  reset
  set term postscript eps color enhanced font "Times,15"
  set view 54,111
  unset xrange
  set xtics +.2
  set ytics +.5
  set yrange [0:5]
  set ticslevel 0
  set xlabel "Lc/Lx"
  set xlabel  font "" textcolor lt -.85 rotate parallel
  set ylabel "R"
  set ylabel  font "" textcolor lt -.85 rotate parallel
  set zlabel "{/Symbol D} P / P_{NS}"
  set xlabel  font "" textcolor lt -.85 rotate parallel
  set style fill transparent solid 0.25
  set pm3d depthorder
  y(x) = sin(x)
  set ytics ("0.40" 0, "0.45" 1, "0.50" 2)
  splot "PressureDesv.dat0" u 1:(0):2 t "R=0.40", "PressureDesv.dat    1" u 1:(1):2 t "R=0.45", "PressureDesv.dat2" u 1:(2):2 t "r=0.50"
  set output "maxwell_speed_distribution.eps"
  replot
  set output
  set term x11
```

I obtained this plot, but I cannot fill this curves with a background tranparent.

[image]

How do I fill these curves with a background tranparency?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, check `help zerrorfill` and `help colorspec` and the following example:

**Code:**

```
### transparent zerrorfill
reset session

### create some test data
set table $Data
    set xrange[0:1]
    f(x,a) = a*sin(pi*x)
    plot '+' u  1:(f(x,2.0)):(f(x,1.7)):(f(x,1.5)) w table
unset table

set view 55,134
set yrange[0.36:0.54]
set ytics 0.05 offset -1,0
set ztics 0.5
set xyplane relative 0

splot $Data u 1:(0.40):2:(0):2 w zerror fc rgb 0xccff0000 lc "red"   ti "R=0.40", \
      ''    u 1:(0.45):3:(0):3 w zerror fc rgb 0xcc00ff00 lc "green" ti "R=0.45", \
      ''    u 1:(0.50):4:(0):4 w zerror fc rgb 0xcc0000ff lc "blue"  ti "R=0.50"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: My apologies, but at the case with a data-file (n-rows, 2 columns), Can I use this comand table $Data? At this case, I would put:   set xrange [1:n-rows]

Comment: @user3618303 How does your input data look like? How many datafiles do you have? Please edit your question and show a few example lines.

Comment: I did this example again, and don't obtain a graph with background transparent. Why did you do this?

Comment: @user3618303 What do you obtain instead? Why did I what? What gnuplot version do you use? Which terminal do you use?

Answer (score 1):

```
set style data zerrorfill
set style fill transparent solid 0.5 border
set xyplane at 0

set xrange [0.3 : 0.6]
set xtics (0.40, 0.45, 0.50)

splot FILE1 using (0.40):1:2:(0):2 title "File 1",\
      FILE2 using (0.45):1:2:(0):2 title "File 2",\
      FILE3 using (0.50):1:2:(0):2 title "File 3"
```

[image]

The column assignments for zerrorfill are  x:y:z:zlow:zhigh